# Fast method for solving volume of a solid of revolution?

Tags: calculus

The example is: Find the volume of the solid figure generated by rotating the area bounded by $y = 3x^2 + 2x + 1$, the x-axis and the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 2$ about the x-axis.

Is there any fast method? The simpler way? Thanks.

Comment: Your thoughts? Do you have any complicated method? Perhaps a slow one?

Comment: Well, I love your sarcasm. By integrals, I know the answer is 2134/15 phi, with using the complicated graph too. I am asking for the simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\pi y(x)^{2}dx=\int_{0}^{2}\pi(3x^{2}+2x+1)^{2}dx
  $$

That's as fast as it's getting.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it would help you

Notice, the volume of the solid generated by rotating the area bounded by the curve $y=3x^2+2x+1$, x-axis, $x=0$ & $x=2$ about the x-axis is $$=\int_{0}^{2}\pi y^2dx$$
$$=\pi\int_{0}^{2}(3x^2+2x+1)^2dx$$

I hope you can solve above integration as your homework.